# Getting input from input-boxes inside tables

Tags: jquery, html-table, textinput

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>

  p { color:blue; margin:8px; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  //region 1
  <!--<input type="text" class="plo" value="some text"/>
  <input type="text" class="plo" value="some text"/>
  <input type="text" value="some text"/>-->

  //region 2
 <!-- <table>
  <tr><td><input type="text" class="plo" value="some text"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" class="plo" value="some text"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" value="some text"/></td></tr>
  </table>
  -->

  <p></p>
<script>
    /*$(".plo").keyup(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("p").text(value);
    }).keyup();*/

    /*$(".plo").keyup(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("p").text(value);
    }).keyup();*/

    $(".plo:last").keyup(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("p").text(value);
    }).keyup();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In this code, the middle input box is chosen and whenever a user enters anything in it, it is displayed  again in the next line. The problem is if region 1 is used, it works fine but if region 2 is used, i.e. its placed in a table, then it doesn't. I have a 10x10 table and I need to process the inputs from each of the cells. Please help

Comment: I've tested (in Chrome) your exact code with region 2 uncommented and editing the text in the middle text box changes the contents of the `<p></p>` section.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you're commenting out both your HTML source and your JavaScript, but after uncommenting your HTML, and changing your code to run in `$(document).ready()` (and removing a redundant call), your commented-out JavaScript has the desired effect.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".plo").keyup(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $("p").text(value);
    });
});
```